# Xcode, how to submit only some targets to the AppStore?

Tags: ios, xcode, targets, tvos

I've been playing around trying to first add a new target to my app, then make my existing code work. However I need to submit my iPad target to the App Store. I'm not ready to submit the other target.

I've tried creating a branch, but reverting back to master trashes my project. Luckily I had a backup.

I'm not sure how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It has changed a bit in Xcode 7.1 beta.

In the "Edit scheme" screen where you setup your archive parameters before you launch "Product/Archive" : select your target in the top left of the screen and then "Generic iOS Device".

But I don't think you will be able to submit your app with a beta release of Xcode.